# Add numbering at the end of every item of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string

I am working on a project where user can input their tweet in textarea then it is broken down to various tweets based on characters length(280) i.e after every 280 length of string new tweet is created.They can also create new tweet by using "[...]" keyword. I have also added button that adds numbering to each tweet eg "I am a tweet 1/2" "I am a second tweet. 2/2". This is where i am stuck. If user types 280 word and press the numbering button it would push 1/2 numbering to another tweet.

Working process:

1. Everytime user types: event is send to handleChange function.
2. Input are split into array based on keyword "[...]"
3. Every item of those array are sent to another function splitOnLength which further split those element based on length(280) and push it to tweetArray.

Problem:
Add numbering to each of those items in tweetArray on button press. eg "I am a tweet 1/2" "I am a second tweet. 2/2".  If user types 280 length string and press the numbering button it would push 1/2 numbering to another tweet.

Comment: Include a small working example of the code along with your question. This will help everyone understand your problem much faster